# dplyr::summarise with filtering inside

Tags: r, dplyr

Inside of dplyr::summarise, how can I apply filters based on different rows than the one I'm summarising?

Example:

```
t = data.frame(
  x = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3, 3, 3),
  y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
  z = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2, 1, 2)
)

t %>%
  dplyr::group_by(x) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    mall = mean(y), # this should include all rows in each group
    ma = mean(y), # this should only include rows where z == 1
    mb = mean(y)  # this should only include rows where z == 2
  )
```

So, the problem here is to apply a summary function to one column, while filtering based on another, all within `summarise`.

One idea was double-grouping, so applying `group_by` on both x and z, but I don't want *all* summary columns to be based on double-grouping, some (like `mall` in the example above) should be based on single-grouping only.

Comment: Two thoughts: either multiple calls followed by a join or something like `ma = mean(ifelse (z==1, y, NA))`.  The second options gives you the answer *within* `summarise` but is, IMHO, very ugly and definitely untidy.

Comment: Yes, the `ifelse` solution works nicely. I agree it doesn't "feel" tidy, but it does the job for now. If I understood better the magic inside these dplyr functions with their symbolic column references I might be able to cook something more elegant together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick option would be to use `ifelse` to filter to the rows you need, make the rest missing and use the `na.rm = T` argument to ignore missing values, like the example below.

```
    dplyr::group_by(x) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(
        mall = mean(y), # this should include all rows in each group
        ma = mean(ifelse(z == 1, y, NA), na.rm = T), # this should only include rows where z == 1
        mb = mean(ifelse(z == 2, y, NA), na.rm = T)  # this should only include rows where z == 2
    )

# A tibble: 3 x 4
      x  mall    ma    mb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   2.5     2     3
2     2   6.5     6     7
3     3  10.5    10    11
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks. I was trying to use `dplyr::filter` inside `mean` but that somehow didn't work, but possibly the syntax got too complicated. Anyway, this solution with `ifelse` works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer by @Colin H is certainly the way to go for this specific example, a more flexible way to approach this could be to work within the subsets of the first grouping operation. This could be implemented with `dplyr::group_split` plus a subsequent `purrr::map_dfr`, but there is also `dplyr::group_modify` to do this in one step.

Note this relevant sentence from the documentation of `dplyr::group_modify`:

> Use group_modify() when summarize() is too limited, in terms of what you need to do and return for each group.

So here is a solution for the example provided above:

```
t = data.frame(
  x = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3, 3, 3),
  y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
  z = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2, 1, 2)
)

t %>%
  dplyr::group_by(x) %>%
  dplyr::group_modify(function(x, ...) {
    x %>% dplyr::mutate(
      mall = mean(y)
    ) %>%
      dplyr::group_by(z, mall) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(
        m = mean(y),
        .groups = "drop"
      )
  }) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 4
      x     z  mall     m
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   2.5     2
2     1     2   2.5     3
3     2     1   6.5     6
4     2     2   6.5     7
5     3     1  10.5    10
6     3     2  10.5    11
```

`group_modify` applies a function to each subset tibble after grouping by `x`. This function has two arguments:

> The subset of the data for the group, exposed as .x.
>
> The key, a tibble with exactly one row and columns for each grouping
> variable, exposed as .y.

Within our function here we use `mutate` to cover the requested `mall`-case first. We do not need any further grouping for that, because that is already covered by the wrapping `group_modify`. Then we apply another `group_by` + `summarise` to cover the different iterations of `z`. Note that this solution is independent of the number of cases in `z` we want to consider. While the two cases in this example can be easily handled manually, this might change if there are more.

If the wide output format with individual columns for the cases in `z` is required, then you can further modify the output of my code with `tidyr::pivot_wider`.

Comment: Very useful, thanks. Didn't know about `group_modify`

Answer (score 1):

Another option and perhaps a little more concise is via subsetting:

```
t %>% 
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(mall = mean(y), 
            ma = mean(y[z == 1]), 
            mb = mean(y[z == 2]))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
      x  mall    ma    mb
* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   2.5     2     3
2     2   6.5     6     7
3     3  10.5    10    11
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another generic way (just like group_modify) to perform custom filtering on a group data while summarizing. This uses dplyr's context dependent expression: cur_data(), which makes the current group's data available inside dplyr verbs like mutate/summary:

```
t %>%
  dplyr::group_by(x) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(
    mall = mean(y),
    ma   = mean(cur_data() %>% as.data.frame() %>% filter(z == 1) %>% pull(y)),
    mb   = mean(cur_data() %>% as.data.frame() %>% filter(z == 2) %>% pull(y))
  )
```

The benefit of using cur_data() is that you can perform any complex filtering or munging before returning the final summary. For more information refer to: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html